# Why is my bool property always false after filtering a list

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class with a bool property like this

```
public class MyClass
{
  public bool IsTrue { get;set;}
}
```

a viewmodel like this

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
      public List<MyClass> MyClassList { get;set;}
    }
```

and have a list of these which I am filtering and iterating through using a foreach loop like this

```
foreach( MyClass c in Model.MyClassList.Where(/*some condition*/))
{
  if(c.ItTrue) //this is always false!!
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

When I run this, `c.IsTrue` always returns false. 
If I remove the filter then `c.IsTrue` returns the correct value (i.e.sometimes true, sometimes false.

Why does adding `.Where(/*some condition*/)` make the bool property always false?
and how can I get this to return correct values.

Comment: In your if-condition it says c.ItTrue. Is that typo only here or is it actually in the code?

Comment: 1) Do you set that `IsTrue` to true ever? 2)Show us that *some condition* that may be `.Where(x=> !x.IsTrue)` in that case definitely `c.ItTrue` will be false

Comment: Do you ever change (set) the value of the `IsTrue` property? If not, remember that [the default value for `bool` is `false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

Comment: I assume you are using a simplified model and so I think that your problem is that whatever /* some condition */ is it filters away the entities where IsTrue actually is true.